# Android SDK manager shows xcopy is not recognized while updating project

Tags: android, xcopy

Whenever i try to update my project using : `android update project --path` , it shows the following error given below. 
my android sdk path is : `S:\Androidapp\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130514\sdk`

i have my java environment variable: JAVA_HOME :

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin
```

ERROR at command prompt:

```
F:\tess-two-master\tess-two> S:\Androidapp\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130514\sdk\tools\android update project -p F:\tess-two-master\tess-two.
'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Updated local.properties
Updated file F:\tess-two-master\tess-two.\proguard-project.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give full path to the `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;` DIR, Instead of the %%% Path

Comment: could you please elaborate this answer where should I put this

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. On a whim, I just copied xcopy.exe from the <\windows\system32> folder and pasted it into the <\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools> folder where android.bat resides, then re-ran the android.bat file. Lo and behold it worked!

It's not an elegant solution, but novices like me settle for brute force when necessary ;-)

- Kirt B.