# Tesseract OCR Build Issue on Windows

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, tesseract

I have Windows 8.1, Android Studio and NDK installed.

I am making an OCR android app and following this tutorial
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/840623/Android-Character-Recognition

I am facing a problem at **building the project**.

I updated my PATH in System Variables to

*`“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin;D:\Softwares\Studies\Android\android-sdk\tools;D:\Softwares\Studies\Android\android-ndk-r10d”`*

And then first I executed *“ndk-build”* command on DOS which executed successfully and then when I executed this command

*`“android update project --path D:\Softwares\Studies\Android\OCR\Code_Project\tess-two-master\tess-two”`*

I got this error:

```
“ `'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.
Error: 

    The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
    Please provide a --target to the 'android.bat update' command. 

”
```

I ve searched all over the internet but could not find the solution, can you please help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: add tess lib in ur app

Comment: @ATRS can you please elaborate?

Comment: first import tess-two project and right click go to properties- select the builders and create the new builder 1) Location:set ur ndk location path 2)working dirctory:tess-two project.

Comment: Have you checked the answers to these similar questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407479/sdk-manager-does-not-find-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511756/android-sdk-manager-shows-xcopy-is-not-recognized-while-updating-project

Comment: @rmtheis Thank God you saw this post. I have tried every method now, I am able to solve xcopy part but the error part is still the same 
**Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
Please provide a --target to the 'android.bat update' command.**
I am using this command:
**android update project --path D:\Softwares\Studies\Android\OCR\Code_Project\tess-two-master\tess-two**

Comment: Glad it worked. You should post your solution to your first question as an answer (to help others), and post your second question as a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: @rmtheis i simply copied xcopy from System32 to my SDK/tools folder but the error is the same. How can i remove this?

Comment: No, that's a different error. It no longer mentions xcopy. You should post your solution as an answer and ask a new question.

Comment: @rmtheis Firstly I am new here and I have reached the limit of asking any more questions so I cant ask secondly the error remains the same, it didn't solve at all and if you really know the ans why cant you answer it here? I ll post the whole solution afterwards. So please if you know the ans, ans it. Thanks

Comment: Does the error still say `'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command`?

Answer (score 1):

I have searched the whole internet and could not find a single place where the proper ans is given.
This had basically two parts:

i) "xcopy" is not recognized

ii) The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
    Please provide a --target to the 'android.bat update' command.

The first part part can be solved by any of the two ways:

i) Moving **xcopy.exe** file from *Windows/System32* folder to *android-sdk\tools* folder       OR

ii) Adding **%SystemRoot%\system32** to PATH in System Variables in Environment Variables. *The PATH must contain **android-sdk\tools;android-ndk-r10d;%SystemRoot%\system32*** at least.

Now comes the second part. Enter this command:
**android update project --path (location of tess-two folder) --target android-19** (19 is the API level here and may vary)

for e.g. *android update project --path D:\Softwares\Studies\Android\OCR\Code_Project\tess-two-master\tess-two --target android-19*

THAT'S IT. Hope it is clear even to someone who is very new. :)

Ps. If you find it useful, please do vote up, I am new and need reputations. :)

Answer (score -1):

[This blogpost](https://droidcomp.wordpress.com/2012/08/04/building-the-tesseract-ndk-library-for-android/) has a elaborate description on how to build tesseract on Windows using Eclipse.

Comment: I am using Android Studio, how can i achieve the same in android studio?